# Possible to change font color on react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a button that when clicked, all the content is transparent.

Is it possible to manually set the text color ? Not background color !

[image: See my "Select"]

I want black color on my font not transparent.

My Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import Select from 'react-select';

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker-cssmodules.css';

const options = [
    { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
    { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
    { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
];



class Test extends React.Component {

    state = {
        startDate: new Date(),
        selectedOption: null,
    }

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {

        };
    }

    handleChange = date => {
        this.setState({
            startDate: date
        });
    };

    handleChange = selectedOption => {
        this.setState({ selectedOption });
        console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
    };

    render() {
        const { selectedOption } = this.state;

        return (

            <div className="grid-container">
                <DatePicker
                    selected={this.state.startDate}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
                />
                <Select
                    value={selectedOption}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    options={options}

                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default Test;
```

[I tried to manually adjust the colors through this link](https://www.color-hex.com/color/d0eae2) But without success !

I want the data to be in black letters on a white background when I click the button.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`react-select` is built in a way you should use `CSS-in-JS` and not `css` like describe here: https://react-select.com/styles.

Then you will be able to use some styling props like:

```
const customStyles = {
  option: provided => ({
    ...provided,
    color: 'black'
  }),
  control: provided => ({
    ...provided,
    color: 'black'
  }),
  singleValue: provided => ({
    ...provided,
    color: 'black'
  })
}
```

And so on.

Answer (score 6):

react-select v5.2.2 gives  the following **style keys** which we can use to style different parts of UI using css

- clearIndicator
- container
- control
- dropdownIndicator
- group
- groupHeading
- indicatorsContainer
- indicatorSeparator
- input
- loadingIndicator
- loadingMessage
- menu
- menuList
- menuPortal
- multiValue
- multiValueLabel
- multiValueRemove
- noOptionsMessage
- option
- placeholder
- singleValue
- valueContainer

Now lets say you want to change the font color of selected option (see the img below)

[image: example selected option]

now what you have to do is you need to find the right **style key** from above and
write a custom css function that's all.

> you can use dev tools to inspect elements and easily find the style keys!

```js
const customStyles = {
    singleValue:(provided:any) => ({
      ...provided,
      height:'100%',
      color:'#08699B',
      paddingTop:'3px',
    }),
  }
```

```js
<ReactSelect
  styles={customStyles}
/>
```

It took me some time to figure this out, hope it helps you and save your time to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the class you want to target this way: in the browser element inspector find the element and find its class. You can that modify its class by adding:

```
.putElementClassNameHere {
 color: black !important;
}
```

You might need !important for the style to be applied.

Comment: Does this work with pseudo-class, like :after in order to add say a red asterisk next to the default select text?

Comment: better to use their style key which i explained below in my answer